# What will be removed if I sync my device with another iTunes?

Tags: itunes, data-synchronization

I had to blow my old iTunes installation. I have all my music and a up to date backup, but I still want to sync my device to change some content. iTunes warns me that "the content of the iPhone will be deleted". What is "content" here? Does it include contacts, messages, apps? Or is just music, books and pictures?

Comment: I'm not sure about that warning, as I have done this and I didn't loose anything. It would be helpful to know if you have a current backup still on your computer as well as what type of computer you have (Mac/PC).

Comment: @IronCraftMan I haven't sync the phone yet. I need to know what exactly will be deleted so I can do a effective back up. I don't think having a Windows system matter.

Comment: You should be able to plug your phone into your computer, and be able to click "Backup Now" without having to sync it.

Comment: @IronCraftMan that's not my purpose... I know how to do a backup, I need to know what will be deleted once I hit the "synchronize" button.

Comment: I don't know. As I said I didn't have anything deleted, and I made sure I had all my music, TV Shows, etc. before pressing that button; and I didn't loose anything. As long as you have a backup, you should be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer depends on how your phone is configured for synchronization.  Note: If you back up your content from the phone to the local new computer first, then though some data will be erased, it will then be copied right back on to your device.

**Entertainment files:**
In most all situations, your music, movies, podcasts, books, and TV shows will be lost as they are replaced with information from the new computer. Apps will usually be preserved.

**Contacts and calendars:**
If your contacts and calendars are being synched through a cloud service, like most people today, your contacts and calendar data won't be lost. If your contact and calendar data is being synched locally through the computer directly, then yes, it would be lost and replaced with the new local data.